# How to understand the synchronization order which is a total order?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In JLS[17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4), it says

> Every execution has a synchronization order. A synchronization order is a total order over all of the synchronization actions of an execution.

I know what is a total order. And I know synchronization actions need to be ordered. But what confused me here is why it is a total order for **ALL** of the synchronization actions. For example, an unlock action on monitor **m** happens-before all subsequent lock actions on **m**. But if simultaneously, there is a lock action on monitor **n**, does it need to be ordered after the unlock action on monitor **m**? If not, then why can all of the synchronization actions have a total order? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. While I don't know the answer for sure, the explanation that I believe best fits my understanding is yes, there is a "synchronization order" between two different locks, because [JLS 17.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2) defines the actions described to be ordered by "synchronization order" as having to be inter-thread (and thus one thread must have dispatched the action before another receives it).

However, here's the catch:

> Synchronization actions induce the *synchronized-with* relation on actions, defined as follows [...]

Only actions ordered by *synchronized-with* produce the required/desired memory effects (i.e. advances the cache state).

So basically although all your "synchronization actions" follow the "synchronization order," (and thus "total order), but only those *synchronized-with* patterns are valid for thread-safety.

Comment: First of all, really thank you for your response. I think your point has enlightened me. Here is what I'm thinking about: from 17.4.3 "A set of actions is sequentially consistent if all actions occur in a total order (the execution order) that is consistent with program order." And also JMM is semantically sequential consistent, which is ensured by synchronizing the race data through sync actions. So the synchronization actions have a total order to ensure JMM's sequential consistency. And what I'm understanding about total order here is about visibility on sync actions.

Comment: That about sums it up. While in theory it's useful to think of the JMM of working like that, in reality I honestly cannot think of anywhere that such a minute detail would be useful; the fact that inter-thread actions behave this way probably isn't even a side-effect of the JMM but more likely to be how most CPU caches work nowadays (correct me if I'm wrong). Either way, if you feel that this detail somehow is useful to your career or project or whatnot, I would be curious for you to share :)